# Dynamic jQuery Selectors, variable problem

Tags: jquery

I'm just trying to make a list of questions with hidden answers that shows upon click. My code hides all divs, but when I click on the anchors, only the last box is toggled.  In this case, every anchor toggles the 5th box, and not their own.

```
for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
    var x = i+"";
    $("#box"+ x).hide();
    $("#feature"+x).click(function(){
        $("#box"+x).toggle(400);
    });
}
```

My basic HTML looks like this, but with 5   pairs:

```
<p><a id="feature1" href="#">1. Absent Message</a></p>
<div id="box1">Stuff here 1</div>
<p><a id="feature2" href="#">2. Alarm Setting</a></p>
<div id="box2">Stuff here 2</div>
```

If I wrote out the functions without using the for loop and string concatenation, the functions do what I want them to. Can someone point me in the right direction? Am I doing something wrong with the string manipulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `x` is shared between *all* copies of the loop, so in the end it's always `5`, and `$("#box"+x)` will always be `$("#box5")` when it's appending at click time.  An easier way would be classes, like this:

```
<p><a class="feature" href="#">1. Absent Message</a></p>
<div class="box">Stuff here 1</div>
```

Then find it relatively, like this:

```
$(".box").hide();
$(".feature").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".box").toggle(400);
});
```

If that's *not* an option, you need to provide the necessary scope to your loop, like this:

```
for(var i=1; i<6; i++){
  (function(x) {
    $("#box"+ x).hide();
    $("#feature"+x).click(function(){
      $("#box"+x).toggle(400);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

By doing this we're passing `i` into the anonymous function, which gets its *own* copy called `x`, not a shared variable scoped to whatever function your `for` loop is in (which is what's currently happening).

Comment: Nick, thanks for explaining the logic behind my variable/scope problem. Your solution worked flawlessly as well as providing a good example of how dynamic selectors should be used. Hope this helps other newbies.